# Are there programs which will reverse the affect of printing something on colored paper?

Tags: printing, printer, colors, gimp, graphics

Suppose that someone printed an 8.5 by 11 flyer out on a colored sheet of paper. For example, this person used paper which was lavender purple long before the paper it went into an office inkjet printer.

We scan their flyer. We now have an image file such as a .jpg or a .png. What computer program, or tool, could I used to create an image of what the flyer would have looked like if it were printed on white paper instead?

How can we reverse engineer the flyer?

Suppose the computer does not have to guess what the background color is. I will tell the computer specifically.

```
HTML HEX CODE #d9d6eb
rgb(217, 214, 235)
hsl(249, 34%, 88%)
```

Inputs to the program are:

- hex code for a specific color (approximately the color of paper, as seen in the scan)
- a scan of a paper flyer with color ink printed on purple paper

The output is an image file (for example, `.jpg`) such that:

- the output file looks like the original flyer, but printed on white paper.

[image: cupcake on purple background]

[image: cupcake flyer on white paper]

Answer (score 2):

tldr **You can not restore original colours**

Any photo editor (photoshop, gimp...) can pick background colour and remove it.

The issue is that inks printed on a coloured paper will not have the same colour than on white paper. And that colour change is not predictable, so the programs can't restore the colours to their originals. The darker the paper the bigger the difference will be.

Answer (score 2):

No, what you are asking for is impossible with desktop printers.

There are 2 problems with this

1. Any ink you use will "mix" with the colour of the paper, and result in a different colour than intended. This could possibly be adjusted by special drivers, if it weren't for the next problem.
2. You cannot print white. To print white you need opaque white pigment. All printers use transparent inks or toners, so the colour of the paper will always show through. There is nothing the driver can do about this.

The only way out is to use a printer that can print white. They do exist, and are used by companies like [PhotoBarn](https://www.photobarn.com/wood-products/) who print photos on things like wood blocks. This works very well, I have seen the result from one of my own photos. Trying to find the (inkjet) printer they use, I found this [laser printer](https://www.uscutter.com/HP-M452dw-Printer-White-Ink), which can print opaque white underneath the colour.